# Update 2 columns for a single case condition

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['RULE'] = 0
df['COLUMN'] = 0
df.ix[((df['IND'].str.upper() == 'YES')), 'RULE'] = 1
```

The above code help me to update Column 'RULE' as 1 if Indicator is 'YES'.
How can I update one more column in the same line. Or should i write one more line of the above code to update the second column. I want to update COL2 also, as 2. Columns 'Rule' and 'Column' are defaulted to '0'

```
IND RULE COL2
YES 1    2
NO  0    0
YES 1    2
```

Comment: [**Note**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated): "Warning: Starting in 0.20.0, the .ix indexer is deprecated, in favor of the more strict .iloc and .loc indexers."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple columns by list and assign list of values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'IND':['YES','NO', 'YES']})

df['RULE'] = 0
df['COL2'] = 0
df.loc[df['IND'].str.upper() == 'YES', ['RULE', 'COL2']] = [1, 2]

print (df)
   IND  RULE  COL2
0  YES     1     2
1   NO     0     0
2  YES     1     2
```

Comment: If Col2 is a list?

Comment: Again, faster :)

Comment: @zipa - so sorry

Comment: @TomJMuthirenthi - `COL2` is column name